# android studio database inspector does not support running multiple statements?

Tags: android

I click `Open New Query Tab`, But I found that it can not run multiple sql statements?

```
INSERT INTO ...;
INSERT INTO ...;
INSERT INTO ...;
INSERT INTO ...;
INSERT INTO ...;
```

it's show message `'INSERT' unexpected`

Where is my usage wrong?

Comment: Yeah, that's a bummer for setting up test data.

Answer (score 0):

A single Sqllite INSERT statement supports mutliple arguments to the VALUES clause to insert several rows

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3) 
VALUES
 (value1, value2, value3),
 (value1, value2, value3),
 (value1, value2, value3)
```

See the section *SQLite INSERT – Inserting multiple rows into a table* in the [sqllitetutorial.net insert guide](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-insert/)